# Scipy minimize - create constraint to have only 5 out of 20

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I was learning to use scipy minimize over the weekend and came across this code below. all credits to this website http://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/Python Optimization

My question is... Is there a way to set up a constraint that limits the solution to only having 2 non-zero elements in x0?

In my problem, x0 are weights for a hypothetical portfolio of stocks. These are multiplied by the respective individual stock returns. I have 20 stocks to choose from, but would only like to have a maximum of 5 stocks (out of 20) in my ending portfolio while minimizing the risk.

What I am trying to get might look something like this:

x0 = [0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

With only 5 non zero values in my array of weights.

P.s. I'm sorry if this is an easy question, I am learning python on my own during my free time.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):
    return x[0]*x[3]*(x[0]+x[1]+x[2])+x[2]

def constraint1(x):
    return x[0]*x[1]*x[2]*x[3]-25.0

def constraint2(x):
    sum_eq = 40.0
    for i in range(4):
        sum_eq = sum_eq - x[i]**2
    return sum_eq

# initial guesses
n = 4
x0 = np.zeros(n)
x0[0] = 1.0
x0[1] = 5.0
x0[2] = 5.0
x0[3] = 1.0

# show initial objective
print('Initial Objective: ' + str(objective(x0)))

# optimize
b = (1.0,5.0)
bnds = (b, b, b, b)
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
con2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint2}
cons = ([con1,con2])
solution = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',\
                    bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
x = solution.x

# show final objective
print('Final Objective: ' + str(objective(x)))

# print solution
print('Solution')
print('x1 = ' + str(x[0]))
print('x2 = ' + str(x[1]))
print('x3 = ' + str(x[2]))
print('x4 = ' + str(x[3]))
```

Comment: This kind of problem can be approached by z3py. See e.g. https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf    (It is not clear which variables are your risk and return, so it is hard to create an example.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

scipy.minimize is all about *continuous optimization* and has strong assumptions including *twice differentiability* of constraints + objective. In it's core, all these algorithms are in the area of *(general) nonlinear-optimization* ([NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming)).

This contradicts your use-case which has a disjunctive nature. See [Integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) for the implications on even more simple problems than yours.

While portfolio problems are usually convex quadratic-programming or second-order cone problems (which is a restriction compared to NLP), people usually use specialized solvers, much more performant and robust compared to NLP-solvers (as exploiting additional assumptions). Convexity also implies tractability (polynomial complexity).

But an QP/SOCP solver won't be enough here due to the disjunctive nature. You will need to go for:

- Mixed-integer QP / SOCP (if problem compatible)
- MINLP

solvers.

The tractability from convexity is lost then (disjunctive)!

These solvers are not available in scipy. And the few non-commercial solvers available are not that easy to setup (especially on windows). A few candidates: [Bonmin](https://github.com/coin-or/Bonmin/tree/master/Bonmin) (convex MINLP; heuristic solution in non-convex case) or [Couenne](https://github.com/coin-or/Couenne) (non-convex MINLP). [OSQP](https://osqp.org/) could work, but i'm sceptical (especially about it's branch-and-bound implementation). The good thing about osqp is, that install should be easy.

You might get some ideas searching for **cardinality-constrained** optimization. Example: [Stanford lectures](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-079-introduction-to-convex-optimization-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT6_079F09_lec11.pdf)

> general convex-cardinality problem is (NP-) hard

(The link also shows some real-world task focused heuristics to render the problem tractable: L1-norm)

If you do not want to explore the complex world of combinatorial-optimization and got some patience + the example reflects your use-case, you can just run your optimization for all selection-combinations (force variable-bounds in [0,0] for all unselected variables) and chose the best result. For your <= 5 out of 20, this will result in ~ 20000 optimizations.